# Treat html form value as a JavaScript statement

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Is there any way to submit a JavaScript statement in a form, (like alert("nefvn");) and then execute it's value as a statement?

```
[..omitted..]
    <script type="text/javascript"
        function doSomething(){
            //Like this?
            var a = document.forms[0].elements[0].value;
            a;
            return;
            //Or just this?
            document.forms[0].elements[0].value;
            }   
    </script>
</head>
</body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="doThis">
        <input type="button" onClick="doSomething()"
    </form>
[..omitted..]
```

Comment: you can use the onsubmit event to house such code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eval(a)` will (try to) execute the javascript code in `a`. Try to avoid it for any non-testing purposes.

Comment: read the documentation of eval as its often abused but this would be proper place to use it

Comment: @DamianSilva You should not get in the habit of using `eval` often, because it's slow, and because unless you are the only one who can affect what string gets passed into `eval`, it's a potential security problem.  And if you're in a situation where you _do_ have complete control of what string gets passed into `eval`, you probably don't need `eval` to begin with.

Comment: @JosiahKeller, and if you were to have complete control, what would you use instead?

Comment: @DamianSilva In what kind of situation?

Answer (score 1):

Set OnClick to "var = 'X'; doFunction()".